# MySQL dump error (#1005 - Can't create table 'novephp_cz_bv.jos_jquarks_customsets' (errno: 150))

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I´m trying dump mysql database from MySQL 5.1. to MySQL 5.5. But I´m getting an error "#1005 - Can't create table 'novephp_cz_bv.jos_jquarks_customsets' (errno: 150)".
Problematic part of script is here:

```
CREATE TABLE `jos_jquarks_customsets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `set_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `set_id` (`set_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `jos_jquarks_customsets_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`set_id`) REFERENCES `jos_jquarks_setsofquestions` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Do you have some ideas?

Thanks, Adam

Comment: `MySQL error code 150: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4061333/2413503